# Regular expression to match pattern and text afterwards until that pattern occurs again, then repeat

Tags: java, regex, kotlin, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regex for my Kotlin/JVM program that satisfies:
Given this line of text `{#FF00FF}test1{#112233}{placeholder} test2`
It should match:
Match 1: `#FF00FF` as group 1 and `test1` as group 2
Match 2: `#112233` as group 1 and `{placeholder} test2` as group 2

`#FF00FF` can be any valid 6 character hex color code.

The thing I'm struggling with is to match the text after the color pattern until another color pattern comes up.
Current regex I came up with is `\{(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})\}((?!\{#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}).*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\{(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})\}(.*?)(?=\{#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lVClwM/1). *Details*:

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})` - Group 1: a `#` char and six alphanumerics
- `\}` - a `}` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\{#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}|$)` - a position immediately followed with a `{`, `#`, six alphanumerics and a `}` char, or end of string.